Change the image of an ImageView by code in Android Studio
I'm trying to get an ImageView by code
It's declared that way in my XML:
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/exo_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@color/cardview_light_background"/>

And I'm setting it by code that way:
val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaItem!!.mediaMetadata.artworkUri!!.path)
view.setImageBitmap(null)
if (bmp != null) {
    view.setImageBitmap(bmp)
    Log.d("TEMPS", bmp.toString())
}

My URL point to a local file saved in my application data asking to the following:
/data/user/0/com.example.euphonia/files/music.zirk.eu/icon/Howling.jpg
My log returns me the following value: android.graphics.Bitmap@f241913
I also tried to set it directly from the URL but it didn't work
To check if my file was incorrect I also tried to set the bitmap the following way:
val help = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.ARGB_8888)
for (i in 0..99) {
    for (y in 0..99) {
        help.setPixel(i, y, Color.rgb(45, 127, 0))
    }
}
view.setImageBitmap(help)

But even with that my file is still not displayed
I also tried to invalidate the view by calling invalidate but that didn't change anything
How can I display an image in an ImageView?

We often use an image-loading library, such as Coil or Picasso.

Make sure you're setting the image to the correct ID. In your case, "exo_image". You're using view.setImageBitmap(bmp). Make sure "view" is referring to "exo_image"

Turns out "exo_image" was already the ID of something inside androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView because after some tests the wrong object was flashing, and just changing the ID to another name fixed the issue, thanks

To do this, I use the picasso library in my app
in build.gradle(app)
    dependencies {
// other
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
    //
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0'
// other
}

in a helper class
/**
 * inserts an image from url into a view
 * Refer to [picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/#license)
 *
 * @param url string with url of the image
 * @param img view with target view
 * @param width int with the image width for resizing
 * @param height int with the image height for resizing
 * @see com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
 */
@JvmStatic
fun addImageUsingPicasso(url: String?, img: ImageView?, width: Int, height: Int) {
    Picasso.get()
        .load(url)
        .resize(width, height)
        .into(img)
}

/**
 * inserts an image from file into a view
 * Refer to [picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/#license)
 *
 * @param file file containing the image
 * @param img view with target view
 * @param width int with the image width for resizing
 * @param height int with the image height for resizing
 * @see com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
 */
@JvmStatic
fun addFileImageUsingPicasso(file: File?, img: ImageView?, width: Int, height: Int) {
    Picasso.get()
        .load(file!!)
        .resize(width, height)
        .into(img)
}

